# Makes Gradle Trust Certificates Distributed Through GPO

Tags: java, gradle, truststore

My company distributed some self signed certificates through GPO, and I want gradle to trust these certificates as well. How can I achieve this?

I have tried adding the following lines to my gradle.properties :

```
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\\Windows\win.ini
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT
```

I wonder if this is the correct approach? Because after I added those lines, the exception saying "unable to find valid certification path to requested target" is gone, but somehow I always got a connection reset exception when resolving dependencies. I'm not sure whether this "connection reset" problem is a completely different matter or my truststore configuration is still not quite right.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the certificates to the truststore/keyring of the JDK that is executing your Gradle instance. Usually, the Env var `JAVA_HOME` points to this JDK, but there are other methods in Gradle to configure it.

In the JDK installation directory, you'll find a default truststore named `cacerts` in `lib/security` (`jre/lib/security` for older Java versions).
There are different tools you can use to modify that truststore. JDK ships `bin/keytool` by default, but there are also graphical tools with easier usability.

Import your certificates into this truststore and Gradle should accept them for your connections. (See [Oracle documentation with examples for keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19830-01/819-4712/ablqw/index.html))

You can also use the configuration property you already listed `systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore=<path>` to point to a modified truststore if you don't want to use the one from the JDK installation.